# There is no default constructor available in com.marlonjones.nimbus.WeatherWatchFaceService.WeatherWatchFaceEngine

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I looked several places, including on here and the answers I found did not help. I also looked through the code of the template that I am using and did not see where I went wrong, so I am sorry if this seems like a bad question. But I am making a watch face and I am trying to extend it from my Engine, WeatherWatchFaceEngine. But when I do this, I get the error that is in the title of this question. What have I done wrong?

This is the code of the watch face:

```
    public class NimbusSplashAnalog extends WeatherWatchFaceService {
/**
 * Update rate in milliseconds for interactive mode. We update once a second to advance the
 * second hand.
 */
private static final long INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

/**
 * Handler message id for updating the time periodically in interactive mode.
 */
private static final int MSG_UPDATE_TIME = 0;

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new Engine();
}

private class Engine extends WeatherWatchFaceEngine {
    Paint mBackgroundPaint;
    Paint mHandPaint;
    boolean mAmbient;
    Time mTime;

    final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new EngineHandler(this);

    final BroadcastReceiver mTimeZoneReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mTime.clear(intent.getStringExtra("time-zone"));
            mTime.setToNow();
        }
    };
    boolean mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;

    /**
     * Whether the display supports fewer bits for each color in ambient mode. When true, we
     * disable anti-aliasing in ambient mode.
     */
    boolean mLowBitAmbient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);

        setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(NimbusSplashAnalog.this)
                .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)
                .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                .build());

        Resources resources = NimbusSplashAnalog.this.getResources();

        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.analog_background));

        mHandPaint = new Paint();
        mHandPaint.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.analog_hands));
        mHandPaint.setStrokeWidth(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.analog_hand_stroke));
        mHandPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mHandPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        mTime = new Time();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
        super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
        mLowBitAmbient = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeTick() {
        super.onTimeTick();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
        super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
        if (mAmbient != inAmbientMode) {
            mAmbient = inAmbientMode;
            if (mLowBitAmbient) {
                mHandPaint.setAntiAlias(!inAmbientMode);
            }
            invalidate();
        }

        // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're visible (as well as
        // whether we're in ambient mode), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
        updateTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        mTime.setToNow();

        int width = bounds.width();
        int height = bounds.height();

        // Draw the background.
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mBackgroundPaint);

        // Find the center. Ignore the window insets so that, on round watches with a
        // "chin", the watch face is centered on the entire screen, not just the usable
        // portion.
        float centerX = width / 2f;
        float centerY = height / 2f;

        float secRot = mTime.second / 30f * (float) Math.PI;
        int minutes = mTime.minute;
        float minRot = minutes / 30f * (float) Math.PI;
        float hrRot = ((mTime.hour + (minutes / 60f)) / 6f) * (float) Math.PI;

        float secLength = centerX - 20;
        float minLength = centerX - 40;
        float hrLength = centerX - 80;

        if (!mAmbient) {
            float secX = (float) Math.sin(secRot) * secLength;
            float secY = (float) -Math.cos(secRot) * secLength;
            canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + secX, centerY + secY, mHandPaint);
        }

        float minX = (float) Math.sin(minRot) * minLength;
        float minY = (float) -Math.cos(minRot) * minLength;
        canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + minX, centerY + minY, mHandPaint);

        float hrX = (float) Math.sin(hrRot) * hrLength;
        float hrY = (float) -Math.cos(hrRot) * hrLength;
        canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + hrX, centerY + hrY, mHandPaint);
    }


    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

        if (visible) {
            registerReceiver();

            // Update time zone in case it changed while we weren't visible.
            mTime.clear(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            mTime.setToNow();
        } else {
            unregisterReceiver();
        }

        // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're visible (as well as
        // whether we're in ambient mode), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
        updateTimer();
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        if (mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver) {
            return;
        }
        mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = true;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        NimbusSplashAnalog.this.registerReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver() {
        if (!mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver) {
            return;
        }
        mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;
        NimbusSplashAnalog.this.unregisterReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver);
    }

    /**
     * Starts the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer if it should be running and isn't currently
     * or stops it if it shouldn't be running but currently is.
     */
    private void updateTimer() {
        mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
        if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer should be running. The timer should
     * only run when we're visible and in interactive mode.
     */
    private boolean shouldTimerBeRunning() {
        return isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode();
    }

    /**
     * Handle updating the time periodically in interactive mode.
     */
    private void handleUpdateTimeMessage() {
        invalidate();
        if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
            long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long delayMs = INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS
                    - (timeMs % INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS);
            mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIME, delayMs);
        }
    }
}

private static class EngineHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<NimbusSplashAnalog.Engine> mWeakReference;

    public EngineHandler(NimbusSplashAnalog.Engine reference) {
        mWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(reference);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        NimbusSplashAnalog.Engine engine = mWeakReference.get();
        if (engine != null) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_UPDATE_TIME:
                    engine.handleUpdateTimeMessage();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the code of the Engine/Service that I am extending from:

```
    public abstract class WeatherWatchFaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
public class WeatherWatchFaceEngine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine
        implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        DataApi.DataListener, NodeApi.NodeListener {

    protected static final int MSG_UPDATE_TIME = 0;
    protected long UPDATE_RATE_MS;
    protected static final long WEATHER_INFO_TIME_OUT = DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS * 6;
    protected final BroadcastReceiver mTimeZoneReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Time zone changed
            mWeatherInfoReceivedTime = 0;
            mTime.clear(intent.getStringExtra("time-zone"));
            mTime.setToNow();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Handler to update the time periodically in interactive mode.
     */
    protected final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case MSG_UPDATE_TIME:
                    invalidate();

                    if (shouldUpdateTimerBeRunning()) {
                        long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long delayMs = UPDATE_RATE_MS - (timeMs % UPDATE_RATE_MS);
                        mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIME, delayMs);
                        requireWeatherInfo();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    protected int mTheme = 3;
    protected int mTimeUnit = ConverterUtil.TIME_UNIT_12;
    protected AssetManager mAsserts;
    protected Bitmap mWeatherConditionDrawable;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Paint mBackgroundPaint;
    protected Paint mDatePaint;
    protected Paint mDateSuffixPaint;
    protected Paint mDebugInfoPaint;
    protected Paint mTemperatureBorderPaint;
    protected Paint mTemperaturePaint;
    protected Paint mTemperatureSuffixPaint;
    protected Paint mTimePaint;
    protected Resources mResources;
    protected String mWeatherCondition;
    protected String mWeatherConditionResourceName;
    protected Time mSunriseTime;
    protected Time mSunsetTime;
    protected Time mTime;
    protected boolean isRound;
    protected boolean mLowBitAmbient;
    protected boolean mRegisteredService = false;

    protected int mBackgroundColor;
    protected int mBackgroundDefaultColor;
    protected int mRequireInterval;
    protected int mTemperature = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    protected int mTemperatureScale;
    protected long mWeatherInfoReceivedTime;
    protected long mWeatherInfoRequiredTime;
    private String mName;

    public WeatherWatchFaceEngine(String name) {
        mName = name;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(WeatherWatchFaceService.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        log("Connected: " + bundle);
        getConfig();

        Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        requireWeatherInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        log("ConnectionSuspended: " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataEvents.getCount(); i++) {
            DataEvent event = dataEvents.get(i);
            DataMap dataMap = DataMap.fromByteArray(event.getDataItem().getData());
            log("onDataChanged: " + dataMap);

            fetchConfig(dataMap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
        log("PeerConnected: " + node);
        requireWeatherInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
        log("PeerDisconnected: " + node);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        log("ConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);

        setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(WeatherWatchFaceService.this)
                .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)
                .setAmbientPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.AMBIENT_PEEK_MODE_HIDDEN)
                .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                .build());

        mResources = WeatherWatchFaceService.this.getResources();
        mAsserts = WeatherWatchFaceService.this.getAssets();

        mDebugInfoPaint = new Paint();
        mDebugInfoPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("White"));
        mDebugInfoPaint.setTextSize(20);
        mDebugInfoPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mTime = new Time();
        mSunriseTime = new Time();
        mSunsetTime = new Time();

        mRequireInterval = mResources.getInteger(R.integer.weather_default_require_interval);
        mWeatherInfoRequiredTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 58);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        log("Destroy");
        mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterruptionFilterChanged(int interruptionFilter) {
        super.onInterruptionFilterChanged(interruptionFilter);

        log("onInterruptionFilterChanged: " + interruptionFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
        super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
        mLowBitAmbient = properties.getBoolean(WatchFaceService.PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false);

        log("onPropertiesChanged: LowBitAmbient=" + mLowBitAmbient);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeTick() {
        super.onTimeTick();
        log("TimeTick");
        invalidate();
        requireWeatherInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
        log("onVisibilityChanged: " + visible);

        if (visible) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            registerTimeZoneService();

            // Update time zone in case it changed while we weren't visible.
            mTime.clear(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            mTime.setToNow();
        } else {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
                Wearable.NodeApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }

            unregisterTimeZoneService();
        }

        // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're visible (as well as
        // whether we're in ambient mode), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
        updateTimer();
    }

    protected Paint createTextPaint(int color, Typeface typeface) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        if (typeface != null)
            paint.setTypeface(typeface);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        return paint;
    }

    protected boolean shouldUpdateTimerBeRunning() {
        return isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode();
    }

    protected void fetchConfig(DataMap config) {
        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_UPDATE_TIME)) {
            mWeatherInfoReceivedTime = config.getLong(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_UPDATE_TIME);
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_CONDITION)) {
            String cond = config.getString(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_CONDITION);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cond)) {
                mWeatherCondition = null;
            } else {
                mWeatherCondition = cond;
            }
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_TEMPERATURE)) {
            mTemperature = config.getInt(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_TEMPERATURE);
            if (mTemperatureScale != ConverterUtil.FAHRENHEIT) {
                mTemperature = ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(mTemperature);
            }
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_SUNRISE)) {
            mSunriseTime.set(config.getLong(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_SUNRISE) * 1000);
            log("SunriseTime: " + mSunriseTime);
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_SUNSET)) {
            mSunsetTime.set(config.getLong(Consts.KEY_WEATHER_SUNSET) * 1000);
            log("SunsetTime: " + mSunsetTime);
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_TEMPERATURE_SCALE)) {
            int scale = config.getInt(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_TEMPERATURE_SCALE);

            if (scale != mTemperatureScale) {
                if (scale == ConverterUtil.FAHRENHEIT) {
                    mTemperature = ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(mTemperature);
                } else {
                    mTemperature = ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(mTemperature);
                }
            }

            mTemperatureScale = scale;
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_THEME)) {
            mTheme = config.getInt(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_THEME);
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_TIME_UNIT)) {
            mTimeUnit = config.getInt(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_TIME_UNIT);
        }

        if (config.containsKey(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_REQUIRE_INTERVAL)) {
            mRequireInterval = config.getInt(Consts.KEY_CONFIG_REQUIRE_INTERVAL);
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    protected void getConfig() {
        log("Start getting Config");
        Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult getLocalNodeResult) {
                Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                        .scheme("wear")
                        .path(Consts.PATH_CONFIG + mName)
                        .authority(getLocalNodeResult.getNode().getId())
                        .build();

                getConfig(uri);

                uri = new Uri.Builder()
                        .scheme("wear")
                        .path(Consts.PATH_WEATHER_INFO)
                        .authority(getLocalNodeResult.getNode().getId())
                        .build();

                getConfig(uri);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void getConfig(Uri uri) {

        Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, uri)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                                log("Finish Config: " + dataItemResult.getStatus());
                                if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess() && dataItemResult.getDataItem() != null) {
                                    fetchConfig(DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItemResult.getDataItem()).getDataMap());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
    }

    protected void log(String message) {
        Log.d(WeatherWatchFaceService.this.getClass().getSimpleName(), message);
    }

    protected void registerTimeZoneService() {
        //TimeZone
        if (mRegisteredService) {
            return;
        }

        mRegisteredService = true;

        // TimeZone
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        WeatherWatchFaceService.this.registerReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver, filter);
    }

    protected void requireWeatherInfo() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            return;

        long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // The weather info is still up to date.
        if ((timeMs - mWeatherInfoReceivedTime) <= mRequireInterval)
            return;

        // Try once in a min.
        if ((timeMs - mWeatherInfoRequiredTime) <= DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
            return;

        mWeatherInfoRequiredTime = timeMs;
        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, "", Consts.PATH_WEATHER_REQUIRE, null)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                        log("SendRequireMessage:" + sendMessageResult.getStatus());
                    }
                });
    }

    protected void unregisterTimeZoneService() {
        if (!mRegisteredService) {
            return;
        }
        mRegisteredService = false;

        //TimeZone
        WeatherWatchFaceService.this.unregisterReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver);
    }

    protected void updateTimer() {
        mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
        if (shouldUpdateTimerBeRunning()) {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated :) (This is also my first real time making a watch face, so please forgive me)

Comment: Is there anything else I need to add to this? Or just input the code exactly as you have? (Can't put it in right now as I'm not near my PC, but I'll comment if it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default constructor accepts zero arguments. You have only a one-argument constructor in `WeatherWatchFaceEngine`.

Add a zero-argument constructor to `WeatherWatchFaceEngine`, whose signiture will be `public WeatherWatchFaceEngine(){...}`

Comment: The implementation depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Just an FYI: when no constructors are declared, a default constructor is implied.